# How to detect blurry blobs?

Tags: python, image, opencv

I would like to detect all the bright spots in this image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NCKi.png)

The code I've tried is via thresholding, but it only detects the very bright ones.  As you can see in the image below.

[image]

But some of the spots are out of focus which I need to also detect them.
Could you suggest a method? The picture below shows the blurred spots that I'd like to detect in yellow circles

[image]

I tried with the following code

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np


path="C:/Slides/Fluoroscent/E_03_G_O_subpics"
imgname="sub_2_4.png"
image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,imgname))

#  constants
BINARY_THRESHOLD = 10
CONNECTIVITY = 4
DRAW_CIRCLE_RADIUS = 18
thr=50
#  convert to gray
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#  threshold the black/ non-black areas
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray_image, BINARY_THRESHOLD, thr, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

#  find connected components
components = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(thresh, CONNECTIVITY, cv2.CV_32S)

#  draw circles around center of components
#see connectedComponentsWithStats function for attributes of components variable
centers = components[3]
for center in centers:
    cv2.circle(image, (int(center[0]), int(center[1])), DRAW_CIRCLE_RADIUS, (0,0,255), thickness=1)

cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path,"result_thresh_"+str(thr)+".png"), image)
cv2.imshow("result", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: I can't say I understand what is the different between the ones circled in yellow and the ones not circled at all

Comment: use a smaller threshold? Or will the noise be reached then?

Comment: You could use a smaller threshold and use connected components or morphology to filter out too small regions.

Comment: @Italy I circled only some of them as an example. But I want to detect all the blurry ones

Comment: @Micka I tried changing the threshold but it had no effect

Comment: from guessing I would say a threshold of 15-30 might work for more blobs. If you can use the color information, this might be good, too.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments you will get better results by changing the threshold values. I changed the values to 20 and 255 respectively and added erosion to get rid of some noise. You can play around with morphological transformations to get the exact desired result. Read more [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) .

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
CONNECTIVITY = 4
DRAW_CIRCLE_RADIUS = 18
img = cv2.imread('blobs.png')
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray_img, 20, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
erosion = cv2.erode(thresh,kernel,iterations = 1)

components = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(erosion, CONNECTIVITY, cv2.CV_32S)

centers = components[3]
for center in centers:
    cv2.circle(img, (int(center[0]), int(center[1])), DRAW_CIRCLE_RADIUS, (0,0,255), thickness=1)

cv2.imshow('Original', img)
cv2.imshow('Thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('Erosion', erosion)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Results:

Threshold 
[image: Threshold]

Erosion
[image: erosion]

Original with circles

[image: circles]

Comment: This is great help. Thank you!. I used color filter to create a binary mask for green areas first. And used blob detection to detect them.But I also need to detect the 3 connected blobs as 3 different blobs. Is there a way to do that with onnectedComponentsWithStats?

Comment: @MaryamSadeghi I don't think you will be able to get connectedComponentsWithStats to detect the 3 connected blobs as 3 different blobs in the threshold image I provided. I suggest you use morphological transforms on your threshold image. You could for example use dilate before erode and see if it creates better results.